# Meteor - broken communication after ddp reconnect

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, serverside-javascript, ddp

I'm writing application consisting of two modules - client and server. Server publishes recordset and function, client subscribes on recordset and calls remote functions. Both modules **run server side**. Everything works as expected until the reconnection of ddp session (i.e server restart).
After the reconnect, remote function calls cease to return any values, subscription is also broken (no events).

I was able to find two operations which used simultaneously cause this effect.
Its "self.ready()" and calling any remote function inside reconnect handler.
If I remove any of that then everything go backs to normal.

Server:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("pname", function () {
    var self = this;
    var id = Random.id();
    self.added("pname", id, {"init": "demo"});
    self.ready();
    Meteor.setInterval(function(){
      var id = Random.id();
      self.added("pname", id, {"init": "test"});
      self.removed("pname", id);
    }, 2000);
  });
  Meteor.methods({
    'demo': function (){
      console.log('demo function called');
      return 'demo';
    }
  });
}
```

Client:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var remote = DDP.connect("http://example.com:3000");
  remote.onReconnect = function() {
    console.log('reconnect');
    console.log('calling remote function inside reconnect');
    var temp = remote.call('demo');
    console.log(temp);
  };
  var collection = new Meteor.Collection("pname", remote);
  collection.find({}).observe({
    "added": function(item) {
      console.log('added', item);
    }
  });
  remote.subscribe("pname");
  Meteor.setInterval(function(){
    console.log('calling remote function');
    var temp = remote.call('demo');
    console.log('Result: ' + temp); //after reconnect this line is not called
  }, 2000);
}
```

So the question is:
What causes such a behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean up the existing publish method or else it will crash as it attempts to publish to a non-existent subscription when you disconnect.

```
Meteor.publish("pname", function () {
    var self = this;
    var id = Random.id();
    self.added("pname", id, {"init": "demo"});
    self.ready();
    var intervalid = Meteor.setInterval(function(){
        var id = Random.id();
        self.added("pname", id, {"init": "test"});
        self.removed("pname", id);
    }, 2000);

    self.onStop(function() {
        Meteor.clearInterval(intervalid);
    });
});
```

You should have also (possibly) seen some debug/helpful info about it in your server console

Comment: I don't understand, I wrote that we can simulate disconnection by resetting(stop/start) server module, so it doesn't know about any previous subscriptions. 
When I add 
self.onStop(function() {
      console.log('onStop publish');
});
then, when resetting client module I can see that it stops publish.

Comment: @user4110474 Ah I see. Unfortunately I don't think I know whats going on in that instance.